# Copy contents of cells and paste into another worksheet under correct date

Tags: excel, vba

I am making an entry sheet for items completed by a person for a date.

INPUT: the user enters a date and it populates the week (on a separate line). Then the user enters numbers under the dates for the week. The Names will always be the same, but the dates can change.

```
      |Jan 1|Jan 2|Jan 3|Jan 4|Jan 5|Jan 6|Jan 7|
Homer    1
Marge          2
Lisa                                        5
```

DATA: This sheet will hold all the dates and names and the items completed.

```
         Homer|Marge|Lisa
 Jan 1 |  
 Jan 2 |
 etc   |
```

My problem is that I have a button that should copy the numbers in INPUT and place them in DATA that corresponds the the same date. I am fine if the data overwrites when they press the button more than once, I just need the data in the right cell.

So far I have snippets of code found on other websites and how to [Move entire row base of call value](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3723-excel-move-row-to-another-sheet-based-on-cell-value.html) but I had a hard time to understand it.

```
Worksheets("INPUT").Range("B2").Copy
Worksheet("DATA").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).Insert
Selection.Pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, Skipblanks:=_False, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: You are actually just transposing data: rows to columns and columns to rows. So it could be done by using the Transpose function if the rows or the columns do not exceed the 65536 items limit which they couldn't because there are fewer columns in a worksheet. Now, do you need the formatting or is it enough just to copy the values?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I do not need formatting, just copying the values is good. I understand what you are saying about transposing the data. I used the Record a Macro to do it. However I do not know how to paste the data so it matches the correct dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Data Transfer (Transpose)

For

```
Const srcFirstCell As String = "C3"
Const tgtFirstCell As String = "E2"
```

[image]

[image]

The images are demonstrating the flexibility of the code:

Yellow: These are the first cells. You can change them as you see fit.
Orange: This is the date that is searched for in the Target Sheet (`DATA`). Only `Jan 1` was manually written to the Target Sheet to show how vital it is that the dates are entered consecutively (one after the other). You will of course have all the dates and the names already written in the Target Sheet. Now you can press the button as many times as you like and the data will only be written to the appropriate cells which wouldn't have been possible with `End(xlDown)` or `End(xlUp)`.

```
Option Explicit

' Assuming that the headers (Names horizontally, Dates vertically) are already
' written in the Target Sheet, the following code searches for the first
' occurrence of the first date in the Target Sheet and transposes the data
' appropriately. It is further assumed that the dates are consecutive.
Sub transposeData()

    Const srcName As String = "INPUT"
    Const tgtName As String = "DATA"
    Const srcFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const srcColumns As Long = 7

    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(srcName)
    With src
        Dim Criteria As Variant
        Criteria = .Range(srcFirstCell).Offset(, 1).Value
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Columns(.Range(srcFirstCell).Column) _
          .Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If rng.Row < .Range(srcFirstCell).Row Then Exit Sub
        Debug.Print rng.Address
        Dim Source As Variant
        Debug.Print .Range(.Range(srcFirstCell).Offset(1, 1), rng.Offset(, 1)) _
          .Resize(, srcColumns).Address
        Source = .Range(.Range(srcFirstCell).Offset(1, 1), rng.Offset(, 1)) _
          .Resize(, srcColumns)
    End With

    ' Write transposed values from Source Array to Target Range.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtName)
    Set rng = tgt.Columns(tgt.Range(tgtFirstCell).Column) _
      .Find(Criteria, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(UBound(Source, 2), UBound(Source)) _
      = Application.Transpose(Source)

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transfer finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub


' While assuming that the Target Sheet was empty I wrote the following code
' which transposes the complete data including headers.
Sub transposeDataComplete()

    Const srcName As String = "INPUT"
    Const tgtName As String = "DATA"
    Const srcFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const srcColumns As Long = 8 ' = 7 days + 1 for 'vertical' headers

    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(srcName)
    With src
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Columns(.Range(srcFirstCell).Column) _
          .Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If rng.Row < .Range(srcFirstCell).Row Then Exit Sub
        Dim Source As Variant
        Source = .Range(.Range(srcFirstCell), rng).Resize(, srcColumns)
    End With
    Set rng = Nothing

    ' Write transposed values of Source Array to Target Range.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtName)
    tgt.Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(UBound(Source, 2), UBound(Source)) _
      = Application.Transpose(Source)

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transfer finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! this works after I i did some tests. However I would like to add the code below.
     _.End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).Insert_ 
I think this code snippet looks for the next empty cell in the column so it can paste the transposed data into it.  Where can I insert it into your code?

Comment: @kamkko: I've done another version which should do the trick.

Comment: @VBasics2008 Thank you very much, the pictures helped with the explanation of how to use. It works perfectly!